# How to keep a program checking to see if the while loop becomes true Java

Tags: java, wait, do-while

My Code:

```
import java.time.*;
import java.time.temporal.*;

class {
public static void main(String[] arguments)  {

    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    int Seconds = now.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);

    do{
        \\ My Code is Here          
    } while ( Seconds <= 00);
```

I have it so that it should repeat when the minute changes but it won't loop unless I start it right before the minute changes. How do get the program to wait until the While becomes true so it will loop?

Comment: Why will seconds ever be less than zero?

Comment: Capture the time before loop, use it as a anchor point

Comment: Careful, that's an octal zero. :-)

Comment: Whatever you do, don't do busy waiting.

Comment: Consider looking at `java.util.Timer` and `java.util.TimerTask` to schedule execution of the code in a background thread at fixed intervals.

Answer (score 0):

You can wait for the amount of seconds to reach a full minute:

```
LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
int seconds = now.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);
if (seconds > 0) {
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60-seconds);
}
```

In fact, if you want to repeat some code every full minute, you should wait inside your loop:

```
do {
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    int seconds = now.get(ChronoField.SECOND_OF_MINUTE);
    if (seconds > 0) {
        TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(60-seconds);
    }
    // your code
    TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);  // sleep for 1 second, so your code doesn't get executed twice per minute
} while(true/*best to have some proper condition in here*/);
```

Comment: so that worked and it looped but about 300000000000 times any way to die that down to 1

Comment: @JacobKiss The original code I posted did that, yes. I edited my answer just a few minutes ago to fix that. On a side note, I am sure you could've figured that one out yourself.